# Is possible to change the default application icon in Xamarin forms cross portable platform app?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, portable-class-library

Is there a way to place the default application icon in the *Portable* component and save the annoying process of setting all the different resources for each platform?.
Having a cross platform App using Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio 2017, the solution have **a Portable project** and the **Android**, **iOS** and **UWP** specific projects.

Comment: App icons are a native feature and thus are bundled at the application project level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this and I doubt if it ever will. At the end of the day you are still building an Android and iOS app which are still compiled through their own tools and compilers.

These tools expects app icons (amongst other things) to be in a certain format, at a certain place. The only thing you (or Xamarin) could do about that is to create it's own format for it and then generate the files in the right size, at the right place for you. I guess this is waaaaay low on the priority list, if it is on it at all. Also, thinking on how to do this, I also believe it is a tough process to get stable.

To help you create app icons in all the right dimensions, have a look at services like [MakeAppIcon](https://makeappicon.com/) which help you a lot. Basically, you just copy and paste it into the right folders and you're done. But I doubt it will get any better than this anytime soon.